# Getting "Key not Found:" while accessing static website on s3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a working website which is developed in react and is hosted as a static site on AWS-S3. Our home page route is `/home` however when we try to access it, we get the following error:

```
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: home/home
RequestId: 0CJ72YSRVM1VR7DT
HostId: EnusXIGM/BWUeBk2Y+jjW2XFYtKjpFB66wf2n9om5L/+yX52JQUviK5ZLPJW6U0moywqGuIBc5M=
```

so, in the root folder, we have put a index.html in the root folder with the following content.

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Coverpage: React.FC = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <>
      <div>I am cover page!</div>
      <button onClick={() => navigate("/home")}>Click me to navigate to homepage!</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Coverpage;
```

and the navigation works.

I really need help to find a way where when the user access the site `http://xxxx`, the site directly navigate to `http://xxxx/home` and the site opens as desired.

Appreciate your help. not sure if we can do it at `reactjs` level or `AWS s3`

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to configure AWS to rewrite most URLs to your React's `index.html`.

1. Create a CloudFront distribution which distributes the S3 bucket.
2. Ensure the distribution's Default Root Object is set to `index.html`.
3. Create a CloudFront function with the code below. This rewrites all requests to `index.html` except for requests to `/static/*`.

   ```
   function handler(event) {
       var request = event.request;

       var parts = request.uri.split('/');
       if(parts[1] != 'static'){
           request.uri = '/index.html';
           console.log('Rewriting: ' + request.uri);
       } else {
           console.log('Not Rewriting: ' + request.uri);
       }

       return request;
   }
   ```
4. Go to the CF distribution then open the default behaviour (or create it if needed) and at the bottom, associate the function as a *View Request* type

Now you can visit the CF Distribution's URL (or your domain if configured) with any path and the React app will show.

---

The other option is to simply set the S3 bucket's Error Document to `index.html`, but this is very hacky and not recommended. Page visits will show the React app but will have undesirable 404 error codes.

Comment: it seems to have worked for me but the images are gone :( 

the url is as follows 

https://d3p8cvyteem5hv.cloudfront.net/home

Comment: Are your images in */static/* ? If they are in a different folder then you’ll need to modify the CF Function code accordingly, such that it does not rewrite any static assets.

Comment: perfect, i just moved from /images to /static and the voila the images are coming>

Comment: @Vivek excellent :) if this solved it you can click the checkmark to accept the answer, so others know what the solution is.

Comment: no the problem did not get solved :(, since i was in the hurry to get the site up, i deployed it on netlify and it worked. will again try to solve this. apologies for being late to reply